# Nuxt.js serious memory leak

Tags: vue.js, memory-leaks, axios, nuxt.js

Nuxt.js + Axios + several other components, SSR. server memory grows from 50Mb to 1500-2000 Mb, then application fails with can't allocate memory error. I thought about Axios, but nuxt-axios should be a solution but it is not. Maybe SSR grows uncontrollably?

What I've tried:

1. updating nuxt.js - no difference.
2. changing Axios to nuxt Axios - no difference.
3. trying to debug - failed.
4. trying to find pages, which doesn't affect memory grow - failed, all do.
5. disabling nuxt axios interceptors - failed, still growing.
6. trying to find big arrays of data with chrome inspector - failed.

[image]

Comment: What version are u using ? And are u using Firebase in your project ?

Comment: No, I don't use Firebase. I tried different versions, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Do you use beforeMount a lot ? A project abt 1 year ago this was my issue of memory leak, and I had my servers on Kubernetes, the memory would go up then crash every 2 days. Give me more details maybe I can help. But mostly the reason is beforeMount, beforeRoute...

Comment: Any advancements on this? I'm having similar issues and nothing I could find helps. I tried profiling it, but the logs are filled with so much garbage from vue/nuxt/webpack that I feel like its impossible to make any sense of it.

Comment: yes, my problem seems to be in the EventBus

Comment: You used a Vue instance as an Event bus? Yeah, thats a common case where memory leaks appear in Vue applications. How did you manage to troubleshoot it, any good articles on it or by chance and code inspections? I don't have that in my application, but if there is a tool that you used to figure out that the event bus was your issue, it might be useful to share

Comment: @HorheGarcia, you mentioned EventBus! by that you mean `$nuxt.$emit` and `this.$nuxt.$on` ?? if so , won't `this.$nuxt.$off` in `beforeDestroy` hook solve that??

Comment: End up finding a solution on this? I know this is a year late, but I'm having the same problems and can find absolutely nothing that will help. My profiling just returns a bunch of webpack and vue garbage which is impossible to understand.